# C# and SQL Server SqlConnection usage causing memory leak

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, database-connection

We are getting a severe memory leak in our C# application. We insulated all the possible suspects and found that the data layer - `SqlConnection` - causing the memory leak. We are executing many `SqlConnection` requests. Approximately 10 requests per second. And we are getting a leak of 200M per day.

We are using the following `SqlConnection` access as base class:

```
public class Access : IDisposable
{
    protected SqlConnection connection;

    private readonly object locker = new object();

    protected void OpenConnection()
    {
        if (this.connection == null)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (this.connection == null)
                {
                    string conn = Config.Data["data"]["mainConnString"];
                    this.connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
                    this.connection.Open();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (this.connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (this.connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    this.connection.Open();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.connection != null)
        {
            this.connection.Close();
            this.connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

All our `SqlConnection` classes inherit from this base class above, and we surround each `SqlConnection` usage with a `using` block

So for instance if we have a `Product` table and a `ProductAccess` the inherits the `Access` class.

We are using the following code:

```
using (var acceess = new ProductAccess ())
{
    Product product = acceess .GetProductById (id);
}
```

Therefore each time we use `SqlConnection` we create a new one and after we finish using it we dispose it (because the usage is surrounded by `using` block)

We are using c# v4.0.30319 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Anyone knows or have any ideas why this memory leak occurred?

Maybe it is related to garbage collection issue or garbage collection configuration?

Maybe this leak related to `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` method call that the `SqlConnection` `dispose()` method call?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem several years ago. I realized it was about Connection Pool. As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) says:

*"Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical connection. It manages connections by keeping alive a set of active connections for each given connection configuration."*

You can either clear the pool after a connection is closed (heavy and inefficient), or you can set the `Min Pool Size`and`Max Pool Size` in your connection string by try and error to optimal values. I believe in your case tuning `Max Pool Size` is much more important. Try to reduce it and watch the result. It is good to start with Min and Max value=1 and test; although this may harm the performance. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, i will check if adding Max Pool Size property to the connection string fix that.

Comment: Please report back. I'm as curious as you

Comment: didn't fix the leak. i think that the leak is related to garbage collection issue , we saw that the leak caused by unmanaged resources (discovered by using c# ANTS Performance Profiler). any other suggestions to fix the leak?

Comment: @user2456342 Do you use any unmanaged resource in your code? If so, do you write any finalizer to release the resource?